# How to install/download darktable 3.6 via cli. Ubuntu 20.04 has only darktable 3.1

Tags: software-installation

I have a dell xps 13 with ubuntu 20.04.I'm confused about how to download darktable 3.6, the latest version. If I could access it Software in ubuntu only has darktable 3.1. Mostly Software is just blank - but that's another question.

Comment: https://www.darktable.org/install/

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer deb-packages, then you can add [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/darktable?field.series_filter=focal) to get 3.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/darktable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install darktable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [Flatpak version of Darktable](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.darktable.Darktable) from your terminal, which is usually more up to date than in the Ubuntu repositories, or than is available on Snapcraft:

```
$ flatpak install org.darktable.Darktable
```

If this doesn't work, you can also install the program from the `.flatpakref` file for Darktable downloaded from the Flathub website, either double clicking it to open in Software, or by passing it to the Flatpak install command instead of `org.darktable.Darktable`.